# Why does solvation release energy?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, heat

Whether dissolving acids and salts is exothermic or endothermic, depends on the lattice and solvation energy. Breaking bonds in the lattice requires energy and is endothermic - that is clear. However, I do not see how solvation would release energy. I do understand that solvation is a type of creating new bonds (and creation of bonds generally releases energy), but how is it that the, eg., Al(H2O)6 3+ is at a lower energy level than Al 3+?

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you think they shouldn't be exothermic ? Does @Mithoron's link answer your question?

Comment: So the answer is entropy change? The system became more orderly so it compensated with releasing energy?